# How to get the total number of pages present in a linkedin post

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to get the total number of pages from this linkedin post

url:
https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:activity:7050104978106974208/

Here's the code that I tried to hover over the post and find the total pages

```
post_url = "https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:activity:7050104978106974208"
browser.get(post_url)

browser.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,900)","") 

achains = ActionChains(browser)
browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='ssplayer-actions center-actions']")
slider_dot = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[@aria-label='Total pages']")
achains.move_to_element(slider_dot).perform()
```

But this code is throwing and error
Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class='ssplayer-actions center-actions']"}

Can anyone please help me in solving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can try it,

(**Here, I assume you're already logged in**.)

The idea is that we need to switch to the **iframe** where the details of the attached document of the post lie.

[image]

And as you can see in the above HTML snippet, the attribute "**aria-valuemax**" holds the information about the maximum value of the page i.e. the number of pages in the document.

Here is the solution:

```
post_url = "https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:activity:7050104978106974208"
browser.get(post_url)

browser.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,900);")
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
    EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe[class='document-s-container__document-element document-s-container__document-element--loaded']")))

element = browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.ssplayer-actions.center-actions')
pages = element.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.ssplayer-progress-bar.meter-animated').get_attribute('aria-valuemax')
print(pages)
```

pages:

```
7
```